# How to set max_session_count variable in deployment.toml in WSO2 IS 5.9.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to increase max active concurrent sessions in WSO2 IS 5.9.0 .
According to documentation-https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/limiting-active-user-sessions-based-on-criteria/

there is one note in this in page where we can perform this by making changes in deployment.toml file by using this variable-

```
authentication.authenticator.session_handler.parameters.max_session_count = “3”
```

Where do i put this in a file?
What is the maximum value of max_session_count?
Will it work just by adding this line in deployment.toml file or are there any more steps involved?

Please Help!!!!!!
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can limit this by using adaptive authentication script. You can know further on adaptive authentication from here https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/adaptive-authentication/.

There is already a sample script for limit concurrent user sessions. That is described on this documentation https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/limiting-active-user-sessions-based-on-criteria/ on how to apply that script.

In that script, there is a **MaxSessionCount** variable is there. You can configure it from the adaptive script. This will be in the application level. This **MaxSessionCount** variable defines how many concurrent user sessions can be there for a user. You can change this from the adaptive authentication script.

Or maximum active sessions can be defined from deployment.toml file from by applying the config. But the priority will be given for the value configured in the script.

Comment: Mam will this work in the case clustering in WSO2?
Or this is something depended on hazelcast?

Answer (score 1):

```
authentication.authenticator.session_handler.parameters.max_session_count = “3”
```

Yes, just adding the above line will work.

However, for better clarity you can put the following configuration to the deployment.toml file instead of wrapping the whole configuration into a single line.

```
[authentication.authenticator.session_handler.parameters]
max_session_count = "3"
```

There is no specified maximum limit for the value of max_session_count.